# Accessing Error Messages within a Rescue Block

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to get access to an error message in a rescue block as a string? For example:

```
def foo
  raise RuntimeError, "This is an error"
end

def bar
  begin
    foo
  rescue RuntimeError
    puts "Rescued"
  end
end

bar
```

Is there any way to gain access to `"This is an error"` from with-in the rescue block? Something like this:

```
...
rescue RuntimeError
    puts <error-message>
end
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify a variable to store the error in

```
def foo
  raise RuntimeError, "This is an error"
end

def bar
  begin
    foo
  rescue RuntimeError => ex
    puts "Rescued #{ex.message}"
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also use the `$!` global inside a rescue block to get the exception object.